# Enable knockout intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, knockout.js, intellisense

I have a new `.js` file, and I have added a reference like this.

```
/// <reference path="knockout-3.3.0.debug.js" />
```

I am still not able to get the `intellisense` up and running for Visual Studion 2010 SP1

I am simple trying the - `ko.applyBindings` ...doesn't work

Is there anything that I am missing to make the `intellisense` work?